# Remove PHP extension from URLs such that the URLs work with or without a trailing slash

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, trailing-slash, file-extension

My directory structure is

```
- Assets
- Dashboard
   - index.php
   - account.php
index.php
about.php
verify.php
```

What I basically want it to be:

1. Remove the .php extension for example `http://example.org/about.php` should be `http://example.org/about/` (including the trailing slash as well)
2. If `.php` is encountered in the URL redirect it back to `http://example.org/about/`

The relevant portions of my .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I'm running it on localhost XAMPP web server.

The works fine but when it encounters the trailing slash it gives me a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RewriteRule` applied to `http://example.org/about/` redirects to `http://example.org/var/www/example/public_html/about/.php` and result in a `404 Not Found` response.

`/var/www/example/public_html`, or something similar, is the absolute path of the directory that contains the files of the website on the server. This type of path shows up because you did not start the [`Substitution`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) (in your code: `$1.php`) with a `/`, which is mandatory in the `.htaccess` file in your case (read the *'URL-path'* paragraph [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)).

**To achieve your goal**, I would use the following *Apache httpd* directives in the root `.htaccess` file (I assumed that all your webpages are PHP files):

```
# Tested with Apache httpd 2.4

### MAP /EXAMPLE/ TO /EXAMPLE.PHP ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+?)/$ /$1.php [END]

### FORCE TRAILING SLASH WHEN ABSENT FOR NON-FILES ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]

### REDIRECT (DIR)/INDEX.PHP TO (DIR)/ ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule (.+/)?index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### REDIRECT /EXAMPLE.PHP TO /EXAMPLE/ ###
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```